# Suspicious Executable - Samsung Magician

Tags: virus, malware

I'm hoping someone may be able to give me some input on an executable I found running every time I boot up my PC. I use the Samsung Magician software which runs on startup, but it wasn't until today I saw a MigrationService.exe running signed by a weird company name (Clonix & CottonCandy). The file is showing as signed by Samsung Electronics Co. like the other Magician processes and is located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Samsung Magician\MigrationService\

I wasn't able to find much on the the company other than it being Korean and is called Cotton Candy, a spin-off of Clonix. I also wasn't able to find pretty much any info on the MigrationService.exe file.

Could this be a third party possibly that Samsung uses to migrate data or could it possibly be malware?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't sound like malware to me. Try uploading it to VirusTotal.

Comment: You can try removing Samsung Magician and see if that is removed with it.  I havent used that software in a long time, but I remember it has cloning software.

Comment: I have Samsung Magician installed, but I dont have that file on my drive.  I do see that they have a migration tool to transfer data from/to SSD.  Maybe its part of that.

Answer (score 2):

It belongs to the Samsung migration software to clone the content of the current system disk to a new SSD (from Samsung). Search in your apps for Samsung Migration ..., you can deinstall that and still keep Samsung Magician (needed for Samsung SSD maintenance). Then this driver is gone after next reboot.